# Что вы знаете о словах образованных от фразеологизмов?

Tags: фразеология

Что вы знаете о словах образованных от фразеологизмов?

Comment: Конкретнее, пожалуйста!

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 0):

У меня есть только пример: [*(не)рукопожатный*](http://www.wikireality.ru/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9).

Answer (score 0):

Слова, образованные от фразеологизмов, в основном являются окказионализмами(авторскими неологизмами). Образуются лексико-синтаксическим способом: все до лампочки > вседолампочество, низкий поклон > низкопоклонство, не в своё время > несвоевременность, злоба дня > злободневный, коптить небо > небокоптитель, снимать пенки > пенкосниматель ,  выше  упомянутый > вышеупомянутый и др.

Иногда новое слово с помощью лексико-синтаксического способа словообразования возникает благодаря «опущению» грамматически зависимых слов и концентрации значения фразеологического оборота в целом на опорном слове. Происходит то, что можно охарактеризовать как сжатие фразеологического оборота в слово. В советское время так возникли, например, слова осадки (атмосферные осадки), партия в значении «КПСС» (Коммунистическая партия), плитка (электрическая плитка), песок (сахарный песок), переживать (переживать горе), нарушитель (нарушитель границы, порядка, закона), освободить (освободить от работы) и т. д. Того же происхождения слова болтать «говорить» (болтать языком), столпотворение (вавилонское столпотворение), помешаться (помешаться в уме), городить (городить вздор) и т. п., появившиеся в русском языке ранее. 
При образовании нового слова лексико-семантическим способом производящее слово может выступать и в совокупности всех своих словоформ, и лишь в какой-то части своей парадигмы, и, наконец, даже в какой-либо одной форме (ср.: часы — час, часы; леса — лес, леса и др.). 
Подробнее здесь:http://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/implikatsiya-kak-forma-dvizheniya-ot-frazeologizma-k-slovu